# Could you give me clear differentiation between different types of Illative Conjunctions?

Tags: conjunctions

Please, I want to differentiate clearly between these three Sets of Illative Conjunctions, which have a relationship with Causality, and Inference:

- to, in order to, in order that, so that. Ex: "He has been working hard, **to** pass."
- wherefore, therefore, so, that. Ex: "He has been working hard, **so** he will pass."
- because, for. Ex: "He passed, **for** he had been working hard."

Thank you.

Comment: Please add an example sentence. // Strunk and White, *Elements of Style*,  states, perhaps somewhat idiosyncratically, that one  should always replace *in order to* by *to*, but many people don't. In general, they mean the same thing.

Comment: @RichardKayser Thank you, I will add examples.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it asks a series of questions.

Comment: _Wherefore_ does not mean _so_; it is an old word for _why_.

Comment: @Xanne you can help me editing the question.

Comment: @KateBunting  you can add this in an answer post.

Comment: @Kate Bunting Check M-W.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth OK - that's a new one on me. Still archaic English, though.

Comment: (2) and (3) show an 'if A, then B' situation. If event A occurs, B is certain to result. In symbolic language, where the arrow means 'demands' or 'gives rise to' ('implies' in the specifying mathematical sense), A → B. Reading this relation from left to right, A therefore B. Usage (2). But looked at in reverse, B because A [happened]. Usage (3). // (1) shows a volitional action taken by a volitional agent to ensure (or encourage) a result. He revised so that he would/might pass the exam. The dog rolled over to be tickled.